# MatAutocomplete Options not highlighted while scrolling through down arrow

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-autocomplete

When I scroll down through the `matAutocomplete` options through the "**down arrow**", the options are not highlighted. In other words, its not indicating which option i have currently selected on hovered. It was working previously. Is this because of any version change of angular material?(Current Angular material version is 9).
Note: This issue exists in all the `matAutocomplete` and `matSelect` in the application
If someone could help me solve this issue, it would be great!

Comment: post your code, please

Comment: Check out this example - https://stackblitz.com/angular/ynrnqrokppx?file=app%2Fautocomplete-overview-example.html. And figure out what your code is missing. It should work by itself.

Answer (score 0):

May be the problem is inside the style files. I had the same problems and it was because some other styles were overwriting mat-active styles and also inside mat-active class mat-option-text class was not specified at all.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).